# Why is python regex not matching special characters?

Tags: python, regex, pandas, csv

I am wondering why the following isn't working. The expression works on Regex101.com. However, when I add â€™ into the spreadsheet, it returns an empty array rather than at least matching that string.

This is the Regular expression:

```
[^A-z0-9\s,.][^-_+=]
```

This is what I'm looking:

```
â€™
Â
```

Try it here (It worked for me):
https://regex101.com/

Here is the code:

```
import pandas as pd
import chardet
import csv 
import re

def get_file_encoding(file):
    rawdata = open(file, "rb").read()
    encoding = chardet.detect(rawdata)['encoding']
    return encoding

#Type in sanitized_ACAS_FULL_1
data = 'sanitized_ACAS_FULL_1.csv'
my_encoding = get_file_encoding(data)
#print(my_encoding)
my_encoding = 'UTF-8-SIG'
df = pd.read_csv(data, encoding=my_encoding, header=None, low_memory=False)

csv_rows = df.apply(lambda x: x.tolist(), axis=1)

sanitized_rows = []
for row in csv_rows:
    for item in row:
        index = row.index(item) 
        row[index] = str(item).strip()
        if 'nan' in str(item).strip():
            row[index] = "NA"

for row in csv_rows:
    for item in row:
        sanitized_rows.append(item)

match = []
for row in sanitized_rows:
    for entry in row:   
        if re.match(r'[^A-z0-9\s,.][^-_+=]', entry):
            match.append(entry)

print(match)
```

Comment: `A-z` is not correct. It should be `A-Za-z`.

Comment: As an aside, this code looks cumbersome and unidiomatic. I would recommend familiarizing yourself with Pandas a bit more.

Answer (score 0):

```
(\GÂ)|(\Gâ)|(\G€)|(\G™)
```

This gets the characters that you want separately. If you want them grouped you can use `(\Gâ€™)` as example. Remembering that `\G` means *start of a match*.

I hope that helps.

Comment: What question are you answering?

Comment: @Toto I'm a "new" user trying to help, it was a regex question and I answered with matching regex strings.

Comment: That's nice, but this doesn't answer the question.